# Develop a secure VoIP Android app

Tags: android, security, webrtc, voip

I want to develop an Android app. It's my first one and it has to be a secure VoIP app. I was told to use webRTC and after a lot of research I'm stuck. I don't get how webRTC works. Can you help me with some steps in developing this kind of apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having worked in the past with `WebRTC`, I just want to share this information here so that it may help people's who just want to start learning from scratch:

--> The very first thing to refer is a straight forward example by `Pierre Chabardes` on the GitHub. Here is the link : [AndroidRTC](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC)

--> You can find here a very straight forward build scripts by `Pristineio` for Android & iOS to build latest version of the required WebRTC library. This requires linux machine. [WebRTC Build Scripts](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts#webrtc-build-scripts)

--> And a very good tutorial here : [Introduction to WebRTC](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/)

This 3 links will get you started and you can start learning from here then.

Hope this helps you and everyone out here.